# Infinite union of convex polytopes is till a polytope? (Union among probability simplex)

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Suppose I have a union set, $\bigcup\limits_{\mathbf{q} \in\mathbf{P}}A(\mathbf{q})$, where $A(\mathbf{q})$ is a $n$-dimensional hypercube defined by

$$A(\mathbf{q}) = \left\{ \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid 0\leq x_j\leq \langle \mathbf{y}(j),\mathbf{q}\rangle, \forall\,j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\} \right\}$$

where $\mathbf{y}(j)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is a non-negative constant vector and indexed by $j,\forall\,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, which means the value of each $\mathbf{y}(j)$ might be different among $j$ and each of element in $\mathbf{y}(j)$ is non-negative. $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{R}^m$  is a probabilistic vector, that is $||\mathbf{q}||_1=1$ and each element of $\mathbf{q}$ is non-negative. $\mathbf{P}$ is a standard probability simplex with $m$ dimensions.

Moreover, I have shown that $\cup_{\mathbf{q}\in\mathbf{P}}A(\mathbf{q})$ is closed, bounded, and convex.

The question is, is the $\cup_{\mathbf{q}\in\mathbf{P}}A(\mathbf{q})$ still a convex polytope?

Based on its closed, bounded, and convex conditions of the union of the sets, I think it is a convex polytope, not a ball, but I got stuck while trying to show that there are finite numbers of half-spaces that can form $\cup_{\mathbf{q}\in\mathbf{P}}A(\mathbf{q})$, which is a definition of a polytope. I think I got stuck because there may not exist a dominant $\mathbf{q}$, that is, different $\mathbf{q}$ may cause different upper bounds of the same $x_j$, due to $\mathbf{y}(j)$ may be different among $j$. I guess there exists some tradeoffs.

I can find $n$ vertices of $\cup_{\mathbf{q}}A(\mathbf{q})$, i.e., $\langle \mathbf{y}(j),\mathbf{q}^*(j)\rangle, \forall\,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, where $\mathbf{q}^*(j)=\arg \max_{\mathbf{q}\in\mathbf{P}}\langle \mathbf{y}(j),\mathbf{q}\rangle, \forall\,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$.

**Edit**: I think the problem can be firstly reduced into $\mathbb{R}^2$ space, that is, for an infinite union of sets of rectangles, if it is bounded, closed, and convex, whether the infinite union is a circle or a convex polygon. However, in this case, I still have no idea.

**Edit**: The reason why I state the union is infinite union is because I thought the number of unions on the standard simplex is infinite. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: My guess at an approach would be: Baire category theorem on the boundary of $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A(i)$, so we get some $i_0$ so that $A(i_0)$ contains a substantial part of the boundary of $A$.  Then try to use that to show the boundary of $A$ contains a face of $A(i_0)$.

Comment: Are the hypercubes "parallel" to every coordinate axes? Otherwise, we have a counter-example.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your reply. I must check out the Baire category theorem. In addition, I can find some vertices of $A$, but after graphing the $A$, I observe that some vertices haven't been found in my first search. I will edit the form of $A(i)$ and $A$ to make the statement clearer.

Comment: I guess you mean $\color{red}{|x_j|}\leq \langle \mathbf{y}(j), \mathbf{q}\rangle$ in the definition of $A(\mathbf{q})$?

Comment: @SangchulLee $x_j$ is non-negative. Thank you for your awareness!

Comment: Also, each element in $\mathbf{y}(j)$ is non-negative for all $j=1,2,3,...,n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the Revised Question.** Indeed, the union $P = \cup_{\mathbf{q}} A(\mathbf{q})$ is a polytope. To show this, let

$$ \tilde{P} = \texttt{ConvexHull}(\cup_{i=1}^{m} A(\mathbf{e}_i))$$

where $\mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_m$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Since $\tilde{P}$ is the convex hull of a finite union of polytopes, $\tilde{P}$ itself is also a polytope (which is spanned by the union of vertices of $A(\mathbf{e}_i)$'s.)

> **Claim.** $P = \tilde{P}$.

*Proof.* Since $P$ is a convex set containing each of $A(\mathbf{e}_i)$, it is clear that $\tilde{P} \subseteq P$. So it suffices to prove that $P \subseteq \tilde{P}$.

To this end, let $\mathbf{x} \in P$ be arbitrary. Then there exists a probability vector $\mathbf{q}$ such that $\mathbf{x} \in A(\mathbf{q})$. To show that $\mathbf{x} \in \tilde{P}$, it suffices to show that there exist $\mathbf{x}^{(i)} \in A(\mathbf{e}_i)$, $i = 1, \ldots, m$, such that

$$ \mathbf{x} = q_1 \mathbf{x}^{(1)} + \cdots + q_m \mathbf{x}^{(m)}. \tag{*} $$

To this end, we note:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x} \in A(\mathbf{q})
&\iff x_j = c_{j} \langle \mathbf{y}(j), \mathbf{q} \rangle \quad \text{for some $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in [0, 1]$} \\
&\implies x_j = \sum_{i=1}^{m} q_i c_{j} \langle \mathbf{y}(j), \mathbf{e}_i \rangle \quad \text{for some $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in [0, 1]$}.
\end{align*}

So, if we set $\mathbf{x}^{(i)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j} \langle \mathbf{y}(j), \mathbf{e}_i \rangle \mathbf{e}_j$, then $\mathbf{x}^{(i)} \in A(\mathbf{e}_i)$ for each $i$ and $\text{(*)}$ holds, concluding the desired claim. $\square$

---

**Answer to the Original Question.** If some of the hypercubes are allowed to be not "parallel" to one another, then there is a counter-example.

Let me construct a counter-example in 2D case. We begin by noting the following observation:

> **Lemma.** Every polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with no acute interior angles can be written as a finite union of squares.

Since its proof is not so fun to write down rigorously, let me provide an animated illustration of how the proof works:

[image: Visual Proof of Lemma]

In light of this lemma, we may weaken the condition on $A(i)$'s by allowing them to be polygons with no acute interior angles. Now we are ready to construct a counter-example:

- Set $P_1  = (0, 1)$, $P_2 = (-1, 0)$, $P_3 = (0, -1)$, and $Q_k = (\sin(\pi/2k), \cos(\pi/2k))$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$
- For each $i$, let $A(i)$ be the polygon with vertices $P_1, P_2, P_3, Q_1, \ldots, Q_i$.

Then $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A(i)$ is the compact convex hull spanned by $P_1, P_2, P_3, Q_1, Q_2, \ldots$, which is clearly not a polygon:

[image: Counterexample]

Comment: I appreciate your answer giving a different aspect! I think the forms of $A(i)$ are "parallel". I will edit my question to make it clearer. Nevertheless, your answer makes me much more understand the problem!

Comment: @jerry, Okay, I came up with an answer to the revised question.

Comment: Fantastic! This is so inspiring. Is the $q_i$ a coefficient in the convex hull $\tilde{P}$ ? I guess it does not mean the element in $\mathbf{q}$.

Comment: @jerry, It is the coefficient in $\tilde{P}$ *as well as* the entry of $\mathbf{q}$. :) That is, the coefficients for the convex combination can be chosen to be the entries of $\mathbf{q}$.

Comment: OK, but if $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n\neq m$, the proof still works?

Comment: @jerry, Oops, I didn't notice that $\mathbf{q}$'s are $m$-dimensional. However, the proof still works with due modifications. I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I can rewrite the proof to deeply understand it. However, I guess the original idea I have (showing the existence of the finite number of half-space) is quite hard to do, right? Since even we know that $P$ is a convex hull, it is still hard to find the "boundary" or "all extreme points (vertices)". Do I think correctly?

Comment: @jerry, Indeed the exact boundary (i.e., faces) of $P$ seems not easy to describe. Depending on the configuration of the points $$\mathbf{c}_i=(\langle\mathbf{y}(1),\mathbf{e}_i\rangle,\ldots,\langle\mathbf{y}(n),\mathbf{e}_i\rangle), \qquad i\in\{1,\ldots,m\},$$ the number of "faces" of $P$ can vary.

Comment: Hi Lee, I am wondering if this statement is correct or not:
"if we set $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_j \langle \mathbf{y}(j), \mathbf{e}_i\rangle \mathbf{e}_j$, then $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}\in A(\mathbf{e}_j)$".  
The question is, $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$ is $n$-dimensional but  $\mathbf{e}_j$ is $m$-dimensional.

Comment: @jerry, Sorry, I exploited the notation, which might be a source of confusion. The $\mathbb{e}_i$'s inside the inner product are $m$-dimensional standard vectors, whereas $\mathbb{e}_j$'s outside are intended as $n$-dimensional standard vectors but I forgot to explain this difference. Perhaps it is much clearer if I used different notation for the latter.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**$\;$  This partial answer shows only that the closure condition is necessary.

Consider the two-dimensional case $n=2$. Start with a square, which can be thought of as a star with four right-angle corners inside a bounding circle. Now add an equal co-centred square rotated by $\frac14\pi$ to poke out of the centres of the sides of the original square, forming a regular eight-cornered star with the same bounding circle. Next add squares to cover each concave corner, creating a regular 16-cornered star enveloped by the original bounding circle. Keep going in this way, covering every concave corner with a square landing a new (convex) corner on the bounding circle. The limiting infinite union formed in this way will be almost a closed disk: namely, an open disk combined with a dense countable subset of its boundary. This figure is bounded and convex but not closed, and it is not a polytope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have shown that my infinite union of sets is closed, bounded, and convex. I am wondering whether these conditions with $A(i)$ is a hypercube show that the infinite union of sets is a polytope.

Comment: OK. I understand now that “I have proved” is meant as a *condition*, not a (questionable) *result*. Thank you for making that clear in the edit.